# CoreData Predicate That Compares Two Properties in a Too-Many Relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to build a predicate that compares two members of a too-many relationship.
The code below more clearly shows my intention, but doesn't seem to work (assume **objects** is the too-many relationship and has members, **member1** and **member2**):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
 @"(ANY objects.member1 ==[cd] objects.member2)"];
```

I appreciate any help in determining a properly structured predicate for this type of comparison.

Comment: Still not sure how to do this type of comparison. What I ended up doing instead was storing a Boolean value as a member of the object that represents the result of the comparison. Would still be interested to know how this comparison would be done, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to fetch the objects which are related to at least one object with
"member1 == member2", you have to use a SUBQUERY:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(objects, $o, $o.member1 == $o.member2).@count > 0"]
```

You can find a similar example in the [NSExpression Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. There was a typo in the code, but the concept worked.